# Stack Site Suggestion - Where to find data site

Tags: discussion, status-declined, site-recommendation

I frequently need to find data sets from fairly far flung locations.  I was curious if any others have similar problems and would appreciate a site where instead of a programming or stats issue, a user could ask the community about suggestions for finding certain data sets.

If this is already in place I'd love to know about it.

Comment: Anything related so new sites should be in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe [stats.se]?

Comment: @Purmou This seems to suggest otherwise: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/what-is-a-good-place-for-how-where-do-i-get-data-on-x-questions

Comment: @Bart never used [stats.se], just checked the FAQ for a moment and it seemed like a match. But it depends, of course. We'll wait for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that site wouldn't be approved as you're just asking for lists of things, something that the Q&A format of Stack Exchange isn't any good for.

You're better off maintaining a repository of links outside of the Stack Exchange network for this kind of thing.  Note that you'll have to deal with link rot, classification of the data, searchability on the formats of data, etc.

This isn't to say that it wouldn't be useful (I love [data.gov](http://data.gov) for example), but it's just something that isn't suited for *here*.

Comment: data.gov is actually one of the reasons I suggested this.  It's so huge and covers so many areas that I find, at least for me, it's overwhelming.  Would it be appropriate to just create a tag for 'government data' or would there possibly be a site like 'govtDataOverflow'?

Comment: Because it's so huge, and covers so many topics, the questions around that data would probably be split among the sites that specialize in those topics.  I don't know that a centralized site around government data would work (too broad).